# Best way to share iCloud storage across regions

Tags: icloud, family-sharing

As is unfortunately the case, Apple is quite restrictive about what you can share across country borders. Copyrighted work I can see why, but iCloud storage...
I have a UK account that I joined in a family share with a non-UK account. I believe I initially changed my account store to non-UK to allow the link up, and then changed it back thinking that would do the trick.    This has led to the non-UK account being associated with the UK store, rendering previous purchase updates impossible.

I have a payment method for both the UK and non-UK regions, but would like to keep my UK account. 
What would be anyone’s suggestions on how to circumvent this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that (at least with iOS 12), it is possible to use the main family share AppStore to receive updates for apps originally from another store. Not sure if intended, but it takes some of the pain out of multi country family shares